# Why is my header not showing?

Tags: html, css

My `<h3>` tag isn't appearing, despite being colored in white, yet my h4 tag shows without any issue. How come?

```css
.progress {
  width:250px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.progress:after {
  content:'\A';
  position:absolute;
  background:#232323;
  top:0; bottom:0;
  left:0; 
  width:100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <h3 style="color: white;">Why am I not appearing?</h3>
  <h4>Subtitle</h4>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t58vhtwr/ (working solution)

Comment: Your fiddle has no h3 or h4 tags

Comment: `:after` overlays the text that's aligned left by default. You can do `text-align:right` on the `<h3>`

Comment: Thanks, apologies I linked to the wrong JSFiddle (now updated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the colour is white, it will show up clearly against a black background.

The black psuedo-element you have positioned, however, is **covering** the white text.

In order to see it, you'll need to make the heading render **above** the black pseudo-element.

For example:

```
.progress h2 { position: absolute; z-index: 5; }
```

Comment: How about this solution: [http://jsfiddle.net/9px8p/121/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9px8p/121/

Comment: @SamJefferies, but now `h4` is hidden as it moved up.

Comment: True, I used the same solution Quentin proposed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.progress h3{position:relative;z-index: 1}
```

```css
.progress {
  width:250px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.progress:after {
  content:'\A';
  position:absolute;
  background:#232323;
  top:0; bottom:0;
  left:0; 
  width:100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.progress h3 {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <h3 style="color: white;">Why am I not appearing?</h3>
  <h4>Subtitle</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better than with absolute.

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: @Aziz, I think, it's clear that he just moves `h3` forwards.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need absolute positioning.

```css
.progress {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.progress h3 {
  background: #232323;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 -10px; 
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 1em 10px;
}

.progress h3 + h4 {
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <h3>Why am I not appearing?</h3>
  <h4>Subtitle</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.progress {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  z-index: 0; /* Create stacking context */
}

.progress:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #232323;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  height: 20%;
  z-index: -1; /* Send to back */
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <h3 style="color: white;">Why am I not appearing?</h3>
  <h4>Subtitle</h4>
</div>
```